# Attack comparison Pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

Are some weaker attacks better due to speed and less power up required to use them? For instance a 50 attack with 2 short power up bars compared to a 60 attack with one long power up bar. Anyone have any insight here?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275296/whats-better-pokemon-attacking/275318 This might help

Answer (score 0):

I only have personal experience to back this up, but it seems that the size of the special attack bar has little effect on the time it takes to charge a single segment. The main benefit of having an attack with several bars is that you can save up more special attacks to chain them together, doing a sort of rapid fire for special attacks. This can be useful if your special move is not super effective against the current opponent you're fighting, but will be against the next one in line once you beat the first.